# Tab bar as subview of view controller's top-level view; not drawn correctly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbar

I have a tab bar controller that I have created programmatically, named `TPastJourneyTabbar`.  When I click on the table view and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, my tab bar class should get allocated and it should get added as subview of another class. I have done this using the follwing code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    TPastJourneyTabBar * tabbar = [[TPastJourneyTabBar alloc]init];

    HGMovingAnnotationSampleViewController *detailViewController = [[HGMovingAnnotationSampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HGMovingAnnotationSampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [detailViewController.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];

}
```

`HGMovingAnnotationSampleViewController` is the class to which I am adding my tab bar as a subview. When I run my application, the tab bar is getting called but it is not getting called completely; i.e., the lower portion of the tab bar, where the title of the tab bar item is written, is not seen. How can I make the tab bar completely visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a design problem here. You shouldn't use a TabBar as a subview of nothing than the AppDelegate's window, as the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) states.